# Postsharp Build Errors after Update to Visual Studio Version 16.8.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, postsharp

After updating visual studio to version 16.8.2, my solution which uses Post Sharp no longer builds.  I didn't upgrade any projects to use .Net 5.  Here are the errors I'm seeing:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\HingeApi.dll' could not be found   HingeApi-tests  C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi-tests\CSC 1   N/A
Error   MSB4064 The "RuntimeGraphPath" parameter is not supported by the "PrepareForReadyToRunCompilation" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.    HingeApi    C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\CrossGenPaths\sdk5.0.100-netcoreapp5.0-r5.0.0-win-x64\CrossGen.proj    11
Error   MSB4063 The "PrepareForReadyToRunCompilation" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.  HingeApi    C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\CrossGenPaths\sdk5.0.100-netcoreapp5.0-r5.0.0-win-x64\CrossGen.proj    11
Error       The process "dotnet" failed with exit code 1.   HingeApi    C:\Users\dbdav.nuget\packages\postsharp\6.5.4\build\PostSharp.targets  381
Error       error: Unhandled exception (PostSharp.Compiler.Hosting.CommandLine.dll 6.5.4 release | .NET Core 5.0.0 (X64)): Value cannot be null or an empty string. (Parameter 'value') See below for details.  HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or an empty string. (Parameter 'value')  HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion.Parse(String value)    HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.PlatformContext.^TTQPa/Ij() in ^f/gziTthOsZk:line 354    HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.PlatformContext.^pFnf8wEt() in ^f/gziTthOsZk:line 114    HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.^pFnf8wEt(ProjectConfiguration[] _0, ProjectInvocationParameters _1) in ^hW2eIAWj:line 795   HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.^pFnf8wEt(ProjectInvocationParameters _0) in ^hW2eIAWj:line 570  HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.LoadProject(ProjectInvocationParameters projectInvocationParameters, Domain& domain) in ^hW2eIAWj:line 541   HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation) in C:\src\PostSharp-65\Public\Core\PostSharp.Compiler.Hosting\PostSharpObject.cs:line 256   HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1
Error       at PostSharp.Hosting.Program.ExecuteImpl() in C:\src\PostSharp-65\Public\Core\PostSharp.Compiler.Hosting\Program.cs:line 957    HingeApi    C:\Dev\repos\hinge\HingeSolution\HingeApi\POSTSHARP 1

I have tried rebuild, clean and build.  Has anyone out there overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostSharp 6.7 is not compatible with .NET 5.0 SDK due to MSBuild changes. .NET 5.0 SDK is installed by Visual Studio Installer when upgrading to VS 16.8.

You can either stay on 3.1 SDK using `global.json` or use PostSharp 6.8. It's still in preview, but the RC should be released soon.

More information is [available here](https://blog.postsharp.net/post/updating-to-vs-168-breaks-build.html).

EDIT: Postsharp 6.8 RC was released.

Comment: I opted to keep my current version of PostSharp and change the SDK I'm using.  It worked like a charm to install the .Net core 3.1 SDK and put a global.json file in directory with my solution (.sln)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to test these:

**1)** target your project to `.net5`, then delete bin and obj folder, after that, rebuild your project again.

**2)** delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache`

**3)** disable PostSharp extension under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**, close VS, restart VS to enable the extension.

**4)** just update the extension if there are the new release version or reinstall the extension again.

If all the steps do not work, I think you should contact with the PostSharp Team.